# adding a partition to a device in use

Tags: fdisk, sfdisk

I have to add a partition to a linux server remotely. The server machine has only one disk. The disk has a lot of blocks which have not been formatted yet. However, because the disk is in use, it is not feasible to unmount the disk for modification.

In this situation is it safe to ssh into the server remotely and add a partition by running fdisk or sfidks with the option '--force', and then reboot? Is there something one has to be careful about?

Comment: @Theophrastus thank you for the comment. The server is Raspberry Pi. This is not used for hosting a website or data.

Comment: @Theophrastus It is entirely possible to do create a new partition on a disk where the other partitions are mounted. This is all done all the time to add new physical volumes to logical volumes or to just add and mount a new partition. Otherwise, one would have to take the system offline and boot from a live USB just to do it wouldn't be viable for any enterprise.

Comment: If you just want to add a partition, then you use `fdisk` just like normal.